# Jython - module in sys.path, but "no module found"

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-6.1, wsadmin

I have some compiled Java classes on my `sys.path` (`['.', 'D:\\PROGRA~1\\websphere_61\\base\\optionalLibraries\\jython\\Lib', 'D:\\program files\\websphere_61\\gmm\\scripts\\jython']`)

On my dev environment these can be used from Jython:

```
from au.com.blah import MagicMonkeys
```

But on a different machine I get the error:

```
 Traceback (innermost last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in ?
 ImportError: no module named au
```

I have checked that the `sys.path` is correct and that the classes are present. How can I debug this further?

edit:

1. I've tried using the `progra~1` notation instead of `program files`, but this didn't help.
2. I've tried added the classes to the classpath before starting wsadmin.bat. This also didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The error "no module named au" is usually because the statement

```
from au.com.blah import MagicMonkeys
```

is trying to find a module named au and find an object or definition named MagicMonkeys in it.

**Solution**
If you need to import all methods from a class/module named MagicMonkeys, you need to write the following:

```
from MagicMonkeys import *
```

And ensure that the path where MagicMonkeys.py is located is in sys.path. If not, then you need to call wsadmin with the following options.

```
wsadmin.bat -lang jython -javaoption "-Dpython.path=the-path-to-your-module" -f yourscript.py
```

Hope this works!